# Get the value of first group of html

Tags: javascript, regex

```
var reg = /([^/]+)(?=/[^/]+/?$);
string = 'http://www.mywebsite.com/map/books/price'
string2 = 'http://www.mywebsite.com/site/food/meat/pork'

var value = str.match(reg);
var value2 = str.match(reg);
```

I am trying to always get the value in between the 3rd slash and 4th slash
which is "**map**" and "**site**",

I tested on http://gskinner.com/RegExr/
but the result always the 2nd group
if someone could help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use basic [split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) function

```
var str = "http://www.mywebsite.com/site/food/meat/pork";
var str1 = "http://www.mywebsite.com/map/books/price";

str.split("/")[3];    // site
str1.split("/")[3];   // map
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it without regex... if you want to make the code less complex.

Manipulate your url string so that you have just your arguments:

```
var url = 'http://www.mywebsite.com/map/books/price';
var req = url.substring( url.indexOf('.com/')+5 ); // 'map/books/price'
var args = req.split('/'); // ['map','books','price']
```

Then, extract your desired argument:

```
var firstArg = args[0]; // 'map'
```